# Running GNU Make targets with parameters

Tags: gnu-make

I have the following Makefile:

```
deploy-1:
    do_stuff $(host1)

deploy-2:
    do_stuff $(host2)

deploy: deploy-1 deploy-2

deploy-production: deploy-1 deploy-2
```

I would like to be able to specify the value of `host-1`/`host-2` from the `deploy`/`deploy-production` task, so that they could basically deploy to different hosts.

Is there a way to invoke a task, from another task, and pass it arguments?

*Note*: The reason why I use `deploy-{1,2}` and not some kind of for loop is that I want to be able to run the targets in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a way to do it using target variables:

```
deploy-1:
    do_stuff $(host1)

deploy-2:
    do_stuff $(host2)

deploy: host1 = host1.net
deploy: host2 = host2.net
deploy: deploy-1 deploy-2

deploy-production: host1 = host1-prod.net
deploy-production: host2 = host2-prod.net
deploy-production: deploy-1 deploy-2
```